# Is it necessary that the potential difference between any two equipotential surfaces in a system be constant?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential

Is keeping $dV$ constant a necessary condition in the formula $$E=-\frac{dV}{dr}$$ for equipotential surfaces ?

Answer (score 1):

Equipotential literally means "the same potential". So if you pick any point on one equipotential surface and pick any point on a different equipotential surface, if you know the potential on each surface then you must know the potential difference between those two points.

The equation you give $\mathbf E=-\frac{\text dV}{\text dr}\hat r$ is true in general for potentials with only a radial component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because equipotential means that the potential is the same, so it's necessary to keep dV the same (constant) for both surfaces.